# R: Accessing a Object Field based on a String

Tags: r

When arranging data for processing in R, there are often trivial transformations that need to be completed.

Consider the following:

1. I want to access *N* members of object `some_set`
2. Specifically the fields: `someset$example1`, `someset$example2`, ..., `someset$exampleN`
3. I intend to obtain a new field based on an iteration of these fields.  For example, mapping *N* binary fields ∋ ∃ ℕ∈[0,*N*]

Intuitively it would make sense to use something like this:

```
for (i in 1:N ) {
   doSomething( get(paste0("someset$example",i,sep='')) )
}
```

However this yields: `object 'someset$example1' not found`

Of course, typing `someset$example1` into the console DOES yeild the correct value.

Begging the question, **if `get(str)` is how we access objects, then how do we access fields of objects?**

Comment: Perhaps taking a quick read to the R intro will help you understand how R works better. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: @marbel I think the observation that the $ and [] operators are functional equivalents is obviously key here, but in this question the key point is the conversion of a string to an indexed variable, which is not covered in the document provided and is not innately obvious.

Comment: the document covers how to index vectors in R. I'm just trying to help you. If you don't find the comment useful, it's fine. Others might find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `[` or `[[` instead of `$`

```
for(i in 1:N){ print(mean(someset[[paste0('example', i)]]))}
#[1] 3
#[1] 8
#[1] 13
```

NOTE: Depending upon the problem, you may not need a `for` loop.  For the above, using `colMeans` would be easier.

If 'someset' is a string

```
Var <- "someset"
for(i in 1:N){ print(mean(get(Var)[[paste0('example', i)]]))}
#[1] 3
#[1] 8
#[1] 13
```

#### data

```
someset <- data.frame(example1=1:5, example2=6:10, example3=11:15)
N <- ncol(someset)
```